# PHP Only one result per url

Tags: php

I am using this code below but although I have the same domain twice only one output it echoing on the page.

```
$urls = array(
    'phpclasses.org' => 'phpclass',
    'phpclasses.org' => 'php',
    'php.com' => 'php'
);

$RankChecker=new RankChecker(1,5);

foreach($urls as $url => $keyword) {
    $result=$RankChecker->find($url,$keyword);

    if ($result!==false) {

        echo $url . " is found at page number  ".$result["page"].".";
        echo '<br>';

    } 
}
```

I need to be able to use same url multiple times.

Why is this not working on the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an array with the same `key` twice. How would you access the value you wanted by `key` if it wasn't unique?

You need to try some other structure for your array.

E.g

```
$urls = array(
    0 => array('url' => 'phpclasses.org', 'keyword' => 'phpclass'),
    1 => array('url' => 'phpclasses.org', 'keyword' => 'php'),
    2 => array('url' => 'php.com', 'keyword' => 'php')
);
```

Then you would need to call your function like `$result=$RankChecker->find($keyword['url'],$keyword['keyword']);` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value of the key 'phpclasses.org'.  Doing

```
$urls = array(
    'phpclasses.org' => 'phpclass',
    'phpclasses.org' => 'php'
);
```

is essentially the same as

```
$urls = array(
    'phpclasses.org' => 'phpclass'
);
$urls['phpclasses.org'] = 'php';
```

In the end, there will only be one key for 'phpclasses.org' in the array

Think about changing it to a multidimensional array, removing the dependance on the key